# How to know which button was clicked if a form has two buttons

Tags: php, forms

I have two forms, one with login and another with logout and they both use the same `controller/form` processor,
 I am using

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']
```

to see if the form is submitted.

But how can I know if login or logout was clicked.

```
$_POST['action'] == 'login'
```

and

```
$_POST['action'] == 'logout'
```

are not working.

okay here is the complete form :

```
<?php

$test = 'default';
if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && $_POST['action'] == 'login' ){
    //do some stuff
    $test = 'login';
}elseif( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && $_POST['action'] == 'logout' ){
    //do other stuff
    $test = 'logout';
}
?><?php echo $test; ?>
            <form method="post" action="">

                    <p>
                    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" value="">
                    </p> 

                    <p>
                    <input type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Password">
                    </p>

                    <p>
                    <input type="submit" name="login" value="Log In">
                    </p>                                                               


            </form>

            <form method="post" action="">
                <input type="submit" name="logout" value="Log Out">
            </form>
```

But the `$test` doesn't change.

Comment: can you post the whole file? Im sure we'll be able to help better if we can see the overall context.

Comment: Now you posted the whole file, you're checking for `$_POST['action']`, but you don't post a value named action. The names of your buttons are `login` and `logout`. By the way, since you have separate forms, you could also add something to the `action` attribute of the form, so the information is already in there.

Comment: Thanks @GolezTrol, I realized that and am using `isset($_POST['login'])` and `isset($_POST['logout'])` now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign names to the buttons:

```
<input type="submit" name="Add" value="Add" />
<input type="submit" name="Delete" value="Delete" />
```

and verify which one is set as:

```
if (isset($_POST['Add'])) {
    // add
} elseif (isset($_POST['Delete'])) {
    // delete
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Give the buttons different names**

If you have a `input` element of type `submit`, you will get a button that posts a value itself. Give it a name and a value, and that value will be posted along with the post data:

```
<input type="submit" name="button1" value="Click me">
<input type="submit" name="button2" value="Or me">
```

The value is often localized and I think you wouldn't want to check for that, but you can just check for the existence of `Button1` or `Button2` in the post variables to see which one was clicked, regardless what their value is.

**Give the buttons (only) different values**

Alternatively, if you know the button value is useful (it contains an id or name rather than a localized text from a template), you could give both buttons the same name (like 'action') and check the value of the post variable instead. In that case, the two buttons behave more or less like a group of radio buttons. Not my preference, but certainly possible and acceptable.

```
<input type="submit" name="action" value="Action 1">
<input type="submit" name="action" value="Action 1">
```

Or you could use a `button` tag in that case, which is a similar but slightly different element. It also has a name and value attribute, but you can specify the text as the content of the element, so you can decouple the value from the text you present to the user. This would be better than using the input version above.

```
<button type="submit" name="action" value="Action 1">Click me for action 1!</button>
<button type="submit" name="action" value="Action 2">Secondary action</button>
```

*Note that `type="submit"` is the default for buttons, so you can omit it, as long as you don't need to support IE7.*

**Checking which one was clicked**

Whichever solution you pick, don't forget to check thoroughly though. There are other ways of submitting a form, [for instance through clicking enter](https://www.tjvantoll.com/2013/01/01/enter-should-submit-forms-stop-messing-with-that/), so make sure to propertly handle the case where neither button was clicked.

```
if (array_key_exists('button1', $_POST)) {
  // Button 1 was clicked
} elseif (array_key_exists('button2', $_POST)) {
  // Button 2 was clicked
} else {
  // Neither was clicked. 
}
```

or for the alternative

```
if (array_key_exists('action', $_POST)) {

  switch ($_POST['action') {
    case 'Action 1': 
      // Button 1 was clicked
      break;
    case 'Action 2': 
      // Button 2 was clicked
      break;
    default:
      // An unknown button was clicked!
      break;
  }

} else {
  // Neither was clicked. 
}
```

Comment: "Give the buttons (only) different values" would be my preferred method

Comment: And there are good cases for that, but it depends on the situation. For instance, when I change "Add to basket" into "Add to cart" on my shop, I don't want my code to fail, because it checks for the text. In that case, I'd prefer to use the 'internal' name of the button rather than the text on it. But if I render a form that shows buttons for all colors I can select, I *might* consider using the value, although in that case too, I don't want to depend too much on the text I present to the user.  Of course, this is different when using `<button>` tag, since its value can differ from its text.

Comment: Yep, button tag is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks. I've added that to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can identify through `isset` function:

```
if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action']=="login"){
  //Login Button Logic
} else if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action']=="logout"){
  //Logout Button Logic
}
```